# How to add different size-guide in different product in magento 1.9.2?

Tags: php, magento-1.9

How to add different size-guide in different product in magento 1.9.2?

I'm having e-commerce store built by magento. In product we are having a size chart which shows the sizes for men and women in detail.

Comment: This question is better suited in the [Magento Stack](http://magento.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Create attributes 
Attribute Code: 'select_size_guide_table',
Scope : Global,
Catalog Input Type for Store : Dropdown,
Catalog Input Type for Store Owner: Dropdown,
Unique Value: No,
Values Required : No,
Input Validation for Store Owner : None,
Apply To : All type Products,
Use To Create Configurable Product: no,
Use in Quick Search: no,
Use in Quick Search: No,
Use in Advanced Search: No,
Comparable on Front-end:No,
Use In Layered Navigation : No
Use In Search Results Layered Navigation : No,
Use for Promo Rule Conditions: No
Position: 0
Allow HTML Tags on Frontend: YES,
Visible on Product View Page on Front-end: No,
Used in Product Listing: No,
Used for Sorting in Product Listing: No

NEXT

Manage Label / Options
In text Field: Select Size Guide Table
Manage Options 
In text field : Women-Bottom-Full

NEXT

Go to Static Blocks -> add New -> Block Title : Size Guide - Women's  Bottom Full, ->Identifier : Women-Bottom-Full,->
Add content or images(Which do you want)

NEXT

app\design\frontend\yourtheme\template\catalog\product\view\type\options\configurable.phtml  REPLACE Below

```
<?php
$_product    = $this->getProduct();
$_attributes = Mage::helper('core')->decorateArray($this->getAllowAttributes());
?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && count($_attributes)):?>
    <dl>
    <?php foreach($_attributes as $_attribute): ?>
        <dt><label class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $_attribute->getLabel() ?></label></dt>
        <dd<?php if ($_attribute->decoratedIsLast){?> class="last"<?php }?>>
            <div class="input-box">
                <select name="super_attribute[<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]" id="attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>" class="required-entry super-attribute-select">
                    <option><?php echo $this->__('Choose an Option...') ?></option>
                  </select>
              </div>
        </dd>
        <?php if(strlen(strstr($_attribute->getLabel(),'Size'))>0) : ?>
                <?php
                $sizeGuideTableAttribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('select_size_guide_table');
                if($sizeGuideTableAttribute):
                    $sizeGuideTableAttributeValue = $sizeGuideTableAttribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);

                    if ($sizeGuideTableAttributeValue != 'No') :
                    ?>
                    <a href="#" class="size-guide-link" id="popup" onclick="div_show()">
                        <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_SKIN); ?>frontend/indianink/images/catalog/product/size-chart.jpg" alt="size guide"/>
                        Size Guide
                    </a>
                    <script>
                        //function to display Popup
                        function div_show(){ 
                        document.getElementById('size_guide').style.display = "block";
                        }
                        //function to hide Popup
                        function div_hide(){ 
                        document.getElementById('size_guide').style.display = "none";
                        }
                    </script>
                    <style>
                    #size_guide{
                        width: 100%;
                        height: 100%;
                        display: none;
                        position: fixed;            
                        background-color: #313131;
                        overflow:auto;
                        top: 0;
                        left: 0;
                        z-index: 9999;
                        overflow: hidden;  
                        }

                        img#close{
                        position: absolute;
                        right: -14px;
                        top: -14px;
                        cursor: pointer;
                        }

                        div#popupContact{
                            width: 40%;
                            margin-left: 29%;
                            margin-top: 5%;
                            background: #fff;
                        }
                        .validation-passed{float: right;}
                        .close{float: right;}
                    </style>
                    <div id="size_guide" style="display: none;">
                         <!-- Popup div starts here -->
                         <div id="popupContact"> 
                            <!--<img src="3.png" id="close" onclick="div_hide()">-->
                            <div class="modal fade" id="size-guide-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" onclick="div_hide()">X</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($sizeGuideTableAttributeValue)->toHtml(); ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                         </div> 
                     <!-- Popup div ends here -->
                     </div>
                <?php endif; //$sizeGuideTableAttributeValue
                endif; //$sizeGuideTableAttribute
                ?>
            <?php endif; //strlen ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </dl>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var spConfig = new Product.Config(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
    </script>
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is using 3rd party extension because Magento does not have this functionality from the box. I recommend using extension Size Chart from Averun company - https://averun.com/magento-size-chart.html. You will able to add different size-guide to different product or category. The extension contains a few international sets of sizes from the box. Also, your customers will have the recommendation to choosing the correct size.